# joomla contact us form retains values after submission

Tags: php, forms, joomla

I have created a simple 'contact us' form by using joomla single contact element (default joomla pack - no form extensions). The problem I'm having is that every form submissions stores field values for the next time the same or a new user fills another form. These stored field values appear as options in a drop-down.

Question: how do I stop joomla store these values or as a minimum not display them.

I'm using PHP mailer for the forms to submit and preferably would like to not store any of it on my site.

Thanks

Comment: Is this intended behavior for Joomla? Seems weird. In either case, could you maybe post the relevant code?

Comment: That's not a Joomla behaviour it's a browser based one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

I think its due to `autocomplete="on"` make it for your contact form, then it will not shows the suggestion for the fields.

If your are using default `com_contact` for the purpose then check the file.

```
components\com_contact\models\forms\contact.xml
```

simply add `autocomplete` off for the fields that not required suggestions. like below.

```
<field name="contact_email"
            autocomplete="off"
            type="email"
            id="contact-email"
            size="30"
            description="COM_CONTACT_EMAIL_DESC"
            label="JGLOBAL_EMAIL"
            filter="string"
            validate="contactemail"
            required="true"
        />
```

Hope its helps..